# Remote disk management on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access

I am trying to use the "Disk management" MMC console from Windows Server 7 against a Hyper-V Server 2012 machine but having no luck so far.

I have...

- enabled "Remote administration" on the Hyper-V machine
- disabled the firewall using `Import-Module NetSecurity -ea Stop ; Get-NetFirewallProfile | Set-NetfirewallProfile -Enabled False`
- started the `vds` service

And yet all I get is *"The RPC server is unavailable"* at the disk management MMC upon connection request. I have read that most RPC interfaces are to be replaced with WinRM over time - has this already been done to Disk Management in 2012 so I am wasting my time trying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nah, it's just me being a blockhead - I was using a management station which did not have the firewall group rules for `Remote Volume Management` enabled, although I was certain it was the case. Running

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Volume Management" new enable=yes
```

on the ***client*** fixed the issue. So RPC for volume management has apparently not been deprecated (yet).